# How can i put a logo and navbar floating on top of revslider jquery

Tags: jquery, slider, revolution-slider

I want to put a logo and navbar on top revolution slider jquery, i want to use bootstrap for the navbar with a hamburger menu aligned to the right.

I put this but doesnt show the slides

HTML:

```
<div class="tp-banner-container">

    <div class="tp-banner" >
      <div class="logo"></div>  
      <ul>  <!-- SLIDE  -->
      ....
```

CSS:

```
.logo{
    background: url('../images/logo-jf.png');
    width: 307px;
    height: 114px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) function.

`$('.tp-banner-container').prepend('<p>content goes here</p>');`

Comment: I want to put the logo and navigation floating on top of the slider.. when i put inside the .tp-banner class, its not showing the slider

Comment: this is an example: https://revolution.themepunch.com/jquery-cover-page/  i want something similar the logo and navbar floating on top of the slider

Comment: Try adding a clearfix before the slider. Since you are using bootstrap you it would be `<div class="clearfix"></div>` before `<ul>  <!-- SLIDE  --> </ul>`

Comment: Without having a look at your code I can't help you much